# Ignorar \n no com o >> do bash

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, shell

Olá tenho um script PHP que eu executo em um servidor, eu o coloquei em um cron. Por razões de segurança e manutenção eu gravo todo o retorno do STDERR em um arquivo, porem mesmo que o arquivo não me retorne nada ele grava uma quebra de linha "\n" no arquivo como posso proceder? Segue abaixo o modelo de execução que uso para gravar o STDERR no arquivo.

> *Obs gostaria que ele armazenasse somente se houvesse um retorno diferente de "\n"

```
usradm01@prod-analytics:~$ php /home/usradm01/monitoringservers.php >> /tmp/monitoring_servers_error.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver,

Eu gravo o arquivo e logo depois uso o comando sed para filtrar o mesmo.. segue exemplo abaixo

```
php /home/usradm01/monitoringservers.php >> /tmp/err.log 2>&1 && sed -r "/^\s*$/d" /tmp/err.log > /tmp/err.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm pode ser feito de varias formas, mas o >> sempre vai incrementar o arquivo

tu pode tentar algum dos comandos possíveis:

```
php /home/usradm01/monitoringservers.php | tr -d '\n'
```

Ou

```
php /home/usradm01/monitoringservers.php | xargs echo -n
```

Ou

```
echo -n  `php /home/usradm01/monitoringservers.php`
```

---

Veja se algum dos comandos anteriores da certo com o >> caso não seria melhor fazer um bash script algo como:

```
saida=$(php /home/usradm01/monitoringservers.php | xargs echo -n)

if [[ -n $saida ]]; then
    echo $saida >> saida.txt
fi
```

Comment: Então eu preciso incrementar ele, porque se ocorrer problemas anoite ou em outro horário teria essas informações, porém gostaria que fosse incrementado somente se houver algum conteúdo.

Comment: Consegui fazendo o uso do php /home/usradm01/monitoringservers.php | sed "/^\s*$/d" >> /tmp/err.log

Comment: Mais vou positivar sua resposta porque me colocou no caminho  certo de pesquisa ;)

Comment: você pode colocar sua resposta como certa

Comment: Como ?? eu não sei..

Comment: cria uma resposta e coloca a solução

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez!!